# $\Vert x \Vert^{2} + \Vert y \Vert^{2} \le \Vert x + y \Vert^{2} + \Vert x - y \Vert^{2} \le 4 \left( \Vert x \Vert^{2} + \Vert y \Vert^{2} \right)$

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I need to prove that the following

> $\Vert x \Vert^{2} + \Vert y \Vert^{2} \le \Vert x + y \Vert^{2} + \Vert x - y \Vert^{2} \le 4 \left( \Vert x \Vert^{2} + \Vert y \Vert^{2} \right)$

is true in arbitrary normed space.
I managed to prove the right inequality, but can't prove the left one.
Would appreciate any help, thank you.

Comment: As a hint, the two inequalities are algebraically equivalent to one another.  Try making a substitution in the right inequality to make it look like the left.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put $u = x+y, v = x - y$. Then your left one is equivalent to the right one with $x,y$ being replaced by $u,v$. So if you did the right one then you also did the left one.

Answer (score -1):

|.| can be ignored when squaring since it gives + value anyway ( considering real numbers only)

Simply open the squares

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).